# Can Canon Rebel T4I take black and white photos with color accents?

Tags: color, selective-color

Can A Canon Rebel T4I shoot B&W pictures with color accents, as you see in some pictures where only one thing has color?

Comment: My suspicion is no but it really does not matter. You can have this done by software easily afterwards.

Comment: [Same question for the T1i](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12979/how-can-i-take-selective-color-pictures-with-my-canon-t1i); the situation hasn't changed.

Comment: Two things, this is called selective coloring, and point an shoot cameras are great at features like this, a DSLR is probably overkill for pictures like this(IMO).

Answer (score 3):

The T4i does not have this feature, but as Itai already mentioned in the comments this can be done in post processing software (e.g. Photoshop) easily. See questions under the [selective-color](/questions/tagged/selective-color) tag for approaches in different software.